# Peewee BinaryJSONField case insensitive search

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, peewee

I am using Peewee with Postgresql and I have a table something like that:

```py
class Test(Model):
  department = TextField(null=True)
  names = BinaryJSONField(default=[])

Test().create(department="Dev", names=["Adams","Baker","Clark","Davis"])
Test().create(department="Adv", names=["Adams","Evans","Frank"])
```

This following queries return like that:

```py
Test().select().where(Test.names.contains(["adams"])).count() # return 0
Test().select().where(Test.names.contains(["Adam"])).count()  # return 0
Test().select().where(Test.names.contains(["Adams"])).count() # return 2
```

As examples above, `BinaryJSONField.contains()` returns nothing,

- If search keys are case insensitive
- Or search keys are part of the the real content

I am wondering if there is any way to search in `BinaryJSONField` case insensitive or part search?

Comment: You can use the `.iregex()` method instead of `contains`, with a regex like `".+(adam).+"`

Comment: `'BinaryJSONField' object has no attribute 'iregex'` it says. @gionni

Comment: True, it doesn't work for BinaryJSONField. Sorry for the bad suggestion

Comment: There is `iregexp` alternatively, but it also give error as `operator does not exist: jsonb ~* unknown. No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`